# Screen flickering on Windows 8.1 HP laptop

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

My laptop screen on my Windows 8.1 [HP Pavilion 14-ab057ca](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04693452) laptop started flickering. I notice that this is happening while I’m watching videos. Is there a particular reason that this is happening? Is it easily resolved? Is it a security concern? This is an image to show what my screen looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because some chipsets cannot keep up with high-definition video. If this happens *only* when playing HD (720p, 1080p or higher), then you might try a more efficient media player, which can help somewhat.

For example, though Windows Media Player caused dropouts and flicker on my ancient laptop, [Media Player Classic - Home Cinema (MPC-HC)](https://mpc-hc.org/) is able to down-convert to the screen resolution and to play without flicker 1080p video.

*Caveat:* If MPC-HC has trouble playing smoothly, it might be necessary to set options:

[image]

These settings are not intuitively obvious, even with hints. It is worth the effort, though, to get smoother playback.